# Saving snapshot dictionary from firebase database to class object

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dictionary

Trying to save the snapshot from my users facebook-firebase information to a User class so I can reference it throughout the app. When I go to convert the snapshot dictionary into the User objects with "user.setValuesForKeysInDictionary(dictionary)" the app crashes, if I comment that line out, print(dictionary["first_name"]) works. Any ideas?

```
var users = [User]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    fetchUser()
}

func fetchUser() {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User()
            user.setValuesForKeysInDictionary(dictionary)

            print(dictionary["first_name"])
        }

       // print(snapshot)

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

Here's the User class file

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var id: String?
    var first_name: String?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing don't use `AnyObject` use `Any` instead.

Suggestion: If you are using **swift4** Use **Codable**  don't use `AnyObject`

Make sure all of your `User` property matches with `dictionary` keys

As per Apple Documentation

> keyedValues
>
> A dictionary whose keys identify properties in the receiver. The values of the properties in the receiver are set to the corresponding values in the dictionary.